# Add a value in a cell based on changes to another cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need some advice regarding what am I doing wrong in the code below. What I am trying to do is that if user enters `"Add"` any cell in `Range ("V"V")`, and then enter any value in the corresponding cell in Range `("R:R")`, then the value of corresponding cell in `Range T (=r.offset (0,2))` gets the same value as the cell in `R:R`, and the corresponding cell in `Range U (=r.offset (0,3))` get the same value as `R:R` cell but in lower case.

Modified the code below by taking out all extra stuff.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range, r1 As Range, Inter As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A9:E9")
    Set A = Range("R:R")
    Set B = Range("V:V")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    Set Inter = Intersect(B, Target)
     Application.EnableEvents = True

    If Inter Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
        For Each r1 In Inter
        If r1.Value = "Add" Then
            r.Offset(0, 2).Value = r.Value
            r.Offset(0, 3).Value = LCase(r.Value)
            End If
        Next r1
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the code give an error?  If so, what is the error and in what line does it occur?  Does it produce a different result than you expect?  If so, what result does it produce and what result do you expect?

Comment: It doesn't produce any error and result. I expect the code to automatically put in the value in, for e.g. T3 and U3 cells from R3 when user enters "Add" in V3. Please let me know if I can clarify anything further.

Comment: What happens when you step through the code when you have entered, "Add" into one of the cells in column V?  Also, does the code definitely run on the event or is it not even being triggered?

Comment: Shouldn't `Range("J4").Value` be `Range("J4").Formula`?

Comment: @OpiesDad: I am not very familiar with excel VBA but after doing some research, I figured out that you can step through the code by hitting F8 for every line of code. However, its not working for me and I could not figure out why. Nothing happens on either hitting F8 or Debug>Step Into. I tried adding "Add" and nothing happens on entering the value in any cell in range "R:R". The expectation is that the code should definitely run once "Add" is entered in any cell in range "V:V" and a value is entered in corresponding cell in Range "R:R".

Comment: @mrbungle The range ("J4") and ("J5") is working fine. However, I took that out of the code now since not having that is not an big issue. I modified the code in my original question above. The main issue is the "Add" issue as I have described above.

Comment: That code should run every time any change in any cell in the worksheet happens.  Where do you have the code?  I don't think F8 will work to start an event procedure.  Instead, put a break point in by left-clicking in the margin to the left of the first line (Set KeyCells...).  This should create a red dot and highlight the row red.  Then, change any cell in the worksheet.  The code should "break" on this line (showing a yellow arrow pointing to the line and yellow highlighting).  Then you can step through the code with F8.

Comment: @OpiesDad I have the code in the worksheet code area (under Microsoft excel objects > Sheet 1). I have a worksheet named "Sheet 1" where I would like this code to work, so I have placed code in that worksheet.

Comment: Did the break point work/does the code get executed upon changing anything in the sheet?  What happens when you step through the code with the break point?

Comment: @OpiesDad I just tried as you suggested - left clicking on the left margin for "Set Keycells" line in the code. It was highlighted in red with a red dot in the margin on the left. I then changed a cell in the worksheet but the there was not any yellow highlighting or a yellow arrow. It remained red.

Comment: Do you have macros enabled?  it doesn't look like your event is firing.

Comment: @OpiesDad I am not sure why breakpoint was not working but I have another copy of the spreadsheet and when I tried it there, it worked and gave me an error "object required". On hitting the debug in the error message, this line of the code was highlighted "For Each r In Inte".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, but I'll explain what your code is doing and maybe that will help.

First, you mentioned in comments that the event is not firing.  This is because you have disabled events and then not captured any errors.  So, if you have an error in the code and then stop running it, the events are not turned back on.  There is no point in turning off the events in this code.  Excel isn't going to capture any additional events until after this event code is finished running.  If you feel that you must, then add an error handler and turn the events back on if there's an error or remember to do it manually.

The second problem that you have is that your code won't logically work.  You have set 'Inte' to be the intersection of column R and the target, but then you set 'Inter' to be the intersection of column V and the target.  The target is whatever cell was just changed, so unless you are changing multiple cells at once, only one of them will have a value, the other one will be Nothing.

The statement "For Each r In Inte" will throw an error if 'Inte' is Nothing and the following statement, "For Each r1 In Inter" will throw an error if 'Inter' is Nothing, and so you will get at error here.  You have checked for 'Inter' being nothing, but would also need to check for 'Inte' being nothing.

With that said, even if you had this check, you would never run this code because one of them is always Nothing.

Assuming that there was somehow something in both of these cells, the code you've written will loop through each 'Inte' Cell and for each 'Inte' Cell, it will loop through each cell in 'Inter'.  Then, whenever 'Inter' is 'Add', it will run the code, setting some value.  So, if there are ANY cells that have the value of 'Add' in column V, EVERY row in range 'Inte' will be updated.  I doubt this is what is intended.

I don't think you quite understand what the "Worksheet_Change" event does.  It will fire EVERY time you change a cell.  So, if you change Cell V15, it will run with Target being cell V15.  Then, if you change cell R15, it will run again with Target being cell R15.  So it only fires for one cell at a time (unless you change multiple cells at the exact same time)

Perhaps, this is what you are trying to do:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     Dim KeyCells As Range
     Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range, r1 As Range, Inter As Range
     Dim ws As Worksheet

     Set ws = Target.Worksheet
     Set KeyCells = Range("A9:E9")
     Set A = Range("R:R")
     Set B = Range("V:V")
     Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
     Set Inter = Intersect(B, Target)

     If Inter Is Nothing Then
          'Do nothing
     Else
          For Each r In Inter
                If r.Value = "Add" Then
                     r.Offset(0, -2).Value = r.Offset(0,-4).Value
                     r.Offset(0, -1).Value = lCase(r.Offset(0,-4).Value)
                End If

          Next r
      End If
      If Inte Is Nothing Then
          'Do Nothing
      Else
           For Each r In Inte
                 If ws.Range("V" & r.Row) = "Add" Then
                      r.Offset(0, 2).Value = r.Value
                      r.Offset(0, 3).Value = LCase(r.Value)
                 End If
           Next r
      End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining. Its making somewhat more sense now. You code is working great if I comment out this line - "r.Offset(0, -1).Value = LCase(r.Offset(0, -4)).Value" since its giving an error of "Object Required". I don't have much knowledge about VBA, so I am assuming that uncommenting this line out would not affect anything. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't put the lower case value in the cell that you want.  I accidentally forgot a parenthesis in that line.  See update.

Comment: If this solves the problem, consider marking this as the answer.

Comment: I figured why this is giving an error. It should be " r.Offset(0, -1).Value = LCase(r.Offset(0, -4).Value)". You are awesome OpiesDad. Thank you for all your help.